# ggplot2 guide/legend on shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, shapes

I have a plot from the following script.

```
require(ggplot2)

df.shape <- data.frame(
AX = runif(10),
AY = runif(10),
BX = runif(10, 2, 3),
BY = runif(10, 2, 3)
)

p <- ggplot(df.shape)
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x = AX, y = AY, shape = 15)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = BX, y = BY, shape = 19)) + 
    scale_shape_identity() + 
    guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15, shape = 19)) )
print(p)
```

This doesn't produce a legend, describing which shape is "A" and which shape is "B". Note that the squares and circles may be close to one another, so I can't generally define the variable based on location. How do I display a "shape" legend?

Comment: `scale_shape_identity(guide="legend")`

Comment: Great! That displays the shape legend, how do I match the legend text with "A" and "B" (for example). I've tried `guides(shape = guide_legend(legend.text = c("A", "B")))

Comment: `scale_shape_identity(guide="legend", breaks=c(15,19), labels=LETTERS[1:2])`

Answer (score 3):

I would reshape my data in the long format using `reshape`:

```
dt <- reshape(df.shape ,direction='long', varying=list(c(1, 3), c(2, 4)),
        ,v.names = c('X','Y'), times = c('A','B'))
```

Then I plot it simply like this

```
 ggplot(dt) +
     geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y, shape = time),size=5) +
     scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,19))
```

[image]

Comment: The legend is great, but the points seem to be plotted in the wrong places.